# Largest $A\subset \mathbb{F}_2^n$ such that no two $a\neq b$ in $A$ add to an element of $A.$

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-fields

If such a set $A$ of size $m$ exists, all its admissible pairwise sums must lie in its complement, thus
$$
\binom{m}{2} \leq 2^n-m,
$$
which gives $$m\leq 2^{(n+1)/2}\qquad (1)$$.

**Edit:**  *The upper bound is wrong. See the wonderful comments and examples below the question and in the answers. I can only accept one answer, unfortunately.*

Since $a+b=c$ is the same as $a+b+c=0$ in characteristic 2, a randomly chosen set of size roughly $2^{n/3}$ will have a solution with some constant positive probability.

For simplicity let $n=2k$. Consider the nonzero elements in $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ as representing the vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^k$
and take "vectors" of the form $(x,1/x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^n.$
Take $$(x,1/x)+(y,1/y)=(z,1/z)$$
equivalently $$x+y+z=0,$$ and $$1/x+1/y+1/z=0$$
as the simultaneous equations we must avoid.

By the Newton-Girard formulas we equivalently want to avoid
$$x+y+z=0,$$ and $$x^2+y^2+z^2=0$$
but in characteristic 2 the second equation is just the equare of the first.

This seems to say, if I pick a primitive element $\alpha$ in the subfield defined above and define
$v(i)=(\alpha^i,\alpha^{-i}+\beta)$ where $\beta$ is a nonzero element in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n} \setminus\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$, the vectors 
$$\{ v(i): 0\leq 2^k-2\}$$ form the type of set we want with $m=2^{n/2}-1.$

**Question:** Is there a better construction which approaches (1).

Comment: How about taking $A$ to be the complement of an index-$2$ subgroup of the additive group of $\mathbb F_2^n$?  This gives $m=2^{n-1}$, which clearly is best possible: if $|A|>2^{n-1}$, then $2A=\mathbb F_2^n$ by the pigeonhole principle, whence $2A\cap A=A$ is non-empty.

Comment: Are you aware that there is an field of study called *sum-free sets* that investigates the largest subset $S$ of an abelian group $A$ having the property that if $a,b\in S$, then $ab\notin S$? Of course, your problem is slightly different in that you only require the condition for distinct $a,b$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-free_set for a few references.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The upper bound is wrong. The problem is that there is no need for the pairwise sums to be distinct. However it is true that there must be at least $m-1$ distinct sums, which gives $m \leq 2^{n-1}$.

This is sharp as we can take $A$ to consist of all elements with nonzero first entry, so all the sums of two elements of $A$ have zero first entry and so do not lie in $A$.

Answer (score 5):

The condition $a\ne b$ can in fact be safely dropped: if $2\cdot A:=\{a+b\colon a,b\in A, a\ne b\}$ is disjoint from $A$, then $0\notin A$ (unless $A\subseteq\{0\}$) and therefore also the larger set $2A:=\{a+b\colon a,b\in A\}$ is disjoint from $A$.

Since $2A\cap A=\varnothing$ is equivalent to $a+b+c\ne 0\ (a,b,c\in A)$, sets satisfying this condition are known as *capsets*. Every capset is contained in a *maximal* (by inclusion) capset; thus, it suffices to study maximal capsets.

As remarked in my comment above, the largest possible size of a capset in $\mathbb F_2^n$ is $2^{n-1}$. [Davydov and Tombak](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244492494_Quasiperfect_Linear_Binary_Codes_with_Distance_4_and_Complete_Caps_in_Projective_Geometry) gave a very non-trivial and delicate classification of maximal capsets of size larger than $2^{n-2}+1$; their result implies, in particular, that any capset of size larger than $5\cdot 2^{n-4}$ is contained in the complement of an index-$2$ subgroup.